# Directive's DOM manipulation not saved when new $digest cycle fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that gets notified when a service is ready, and should then manipulate its DOM.

DOM gets manipulated ok, but whenever I filter back and forth the ng-repeat this directive is in (when a new $digest cycle fires), the directive reverts back to its initial state (without modified DOM, i.e. it's compile state).

Once the directive gets notified by the service and DOM manipulate, the scope and DOM will not change. So the state it is then, is its final form, and it's how I want DOM be whenever new $digest cycle fires.

How to solve this problem?

How can I save async DOM manipulations so that when next $digest fires it's still there?

The reason I want to do it this way, is that the data will not change after the directive gets notified, and thus, don't want to and need to use watchers.

Thanks.

**Code**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myItem', function (_, myService) {
    var pricesToShow = 3,
        textToShow = 'Fetching Data';

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'tpl/myItem.html',
        compile: function($templateElement) {
            // THIS IS THE STATE DIRECTIVE REVERTS TO WHENEVER ITS RERENDERED - WHY?
            var $pricesElem = $templateElement.children().eq(0).children().eq(-1),
                html= '';

            if (pricesToShow) {
                html = '<span>' + textToShow + '</span>';

                _.times(pricesToShow, function() {
                    html += '<div class="pricetag"><span class="sid">' + i + '</span> <span class="price"></span> <span class="currency"></span></div>';
                });

                $pricesElem.append(html);
            }

            return function($scope, $linkElement, $linkAttributes, ctrl) {
                var id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
                    $priceTagElems = $linkElement.children().eq(0).children().eq(-1).children().slice(1);

                $scope.$on('$destroy', onDestroy);

                if (myService.getServices().isDoneProcessing) {
                    showPrices();
                } else {
                    myService.registerObserver(id, updatePrices);
                }

                function onDestroy() {
                    myService.unregisterObserver(id);
                }

                function showPrices(isAsyncCall) {

                    if (!isAsyncCall && !$scope.trip.prices) {
                        updatePrices();
                    } else if (!isAsyncCall && $scope.trip.prices) {
                        // DOM should now be in its final form - but appears to be in its compile form :(
                        return;
                    }

                    // THESE CHANGES TO DOM WON'T BE SAVED FOR THE NEXT $DIGEST - WHY?
                    _.each($scope.trip.prices, function(price, i) {
                        $priceTagElems.eq(i).children().eq(0)
                            .text(price.sid).next()
                            .text(price.value.toFixed()).next()
                            .text(price.currency);
                    });
                }

                function updatePrices(isNotificationCallback) {
                    if ($scope.trip.prices) { return; }

                    $scope.trip.prices = [];

                    _.each($scope.trip.values, function(item) {
                        $scope.trip.prices.push({'sid': item.sid, 'value': item.price.value, 'currency': item.price.currency});
                    });

                    $scope.trip.prices.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a.value - b.value;
                    });

                    if (isNotificationCallback) {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.trip.prices = _.first($scope.trip.prices, pricesToShow);
                            showPrices(true);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $scope.trip.prices = _.first($scope.trip.prices, pricesToShow);
                    }
                }
            };
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            // Some logic ...
        }
    };

});
```

**myItem.html**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>..some bo-text spans..</div>
        <div>..some bo-text spans..</div>
        <div class="prices">..this will be replaced by compile function and in async callback function..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ng-repeat**

```
<div bindonce="trip" ng-repeat="trip in trips | myFilter:customFilters | limitTo: 20 track by trip.key" my-item="">Replaced by directive</div>
```

**myFilter**

```
return function (trips, filter) {
    var filtered = [];
    _.each(trips, function(element) {
        var match = hasMatch(element, filter);
        if (match) {
           filtered.push(element);
        }
    });
    return filtered;
};
```

Comment: I don't think your method showPrices will survive if you're not saving it in the scope.

Comment: @AlexC Why should it be saved in scope? This is kind of bindonce but wait for prices thing I'm after

Comment: I never define methods (or attributes now that I think about it) that are not either part of a scope or part of an object (service, factory etc). Feel free to prove me wrong but I think it's the way to go if you don't want things to be ephemeral.

Comment: What does your custom filter ? If it rebuilds a collection of objects without the `$$hashKey` added by the `ngRepeat` compile function, all your `myItem` directive instances are logically rebuilt. I imagine your filter is returning a new object each time. That has a HUGE impact on `ngRepeat` performance.

Comment: @lib3d Updated the code with filter function… I've tried removing "track by trip.key" from ng-repeat but has not effect

Comment: Adding a breakpoint at `compile` start, does it stop at it? And logging `element.$$hashKey`, does it log a key (which is equal to the `key` property if still using `track by trip.key` statement)?

Comment: @lib3d yes, it stops. But $$hasKey is `undefined` in both templateElemet and link element which to me doesn't come by surprise if using track by.

Comment: @lib3d When using `track by trip.key` the `$$hashKey` is not created, i.e. `undefined` but when not using it `$$hashKey` will be created

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49810/discussion-between-micadelli-and-lib3d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a conclusion of our discussion:

- reversing the order combined with the `limitTo` filter implies scopes being destroyed, and elements too
- the link function is then recalled when entety reentering the filtered list, using the element at its post compilation state, that is to say without the dom transforms carried out during previous linking function scope life cycle

**All this means that the occuring behaviour is absolutely normal.**

As a solution, an element, if already linked (so transformed), should not be removed, only hidden. Cloned and storing somehow on the entities is not recommended. Better have a full custom filter flagging entities already shown once so that they can be simply hidden in the ordered and bounded list.